# SPOnline & modern experience : how to add WP in the new Event.Aspx page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, hive

I love the new modern experience but everything is not deployed yet.

**What i would like to achieve**

By adding the new Events WebPart, when I click on "Add a new event", it redirects me to a special page in **/_layouts/15/Event.aspx?ListGuid=&Mode=Edit**

I would like to brand this page a bit, by adding some WP like Yammer feed or things like that. This page would be kinda template for when users want to create Events.

**My questions**

Because this "Event.aspx" page is stored in SP Hive, i can not find it elsewhere.

- Is it possible to at least copy it ?
- If not, How can I copy the Event form to another page ?

So thanks to share your lights with me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, unfortunately there is no way to customize the page or make a copy of that page. The page also does not support calendars with custom columns/content types.

Comment: Thanks @sssreddy, we've worked around this issue by adding an extension that adds a Yammer feed to the page. It is a bit dirty, but well, we do what we got to do with what we have :)
Thanks for your time